# Как отправить третий параметр на сервер

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу помощи! Необходимо отправлять с помощью Ajax данные на сервер, в своем приложении использую jQuery плагин [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) ([перевод Jeditable на русский](http://it-route.ru/jeditable_manual_ru/)).

Вот здесь описано как отправить два параметра name и id:
[image]

**У меня вопрос: Как отправить третий параметр?**

Поясню, у меня есть таблица:

[image]

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Коэффициент</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>';
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id="AAATc6AAEAABQz+AAA" class="editable">0.000000000000000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

После редактирования нужного мне поля нажимаю **ENTER** и вижу, что улетают два параметра один параметр это *KOEF_koef* (значение самого **input**), второй это *ROWID_koef* это значение берется из атрибута *id*:

```
$('td.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
    indicator : 'Сохраняется...',
    name : 'KOEF_koef',
    id : 'ROWID_koef'
});
```

в консоли вижу, что параметры улетели:

[image]

А как мне добавить третий параметр?

Третий параметр в идеале хотелось бы получать из DOM`а вот такой выборкой:

```
$('#info-month-count').text()
```

Я полагал, что в таком случае сценарий может выглядеть так (однако не сработало):

```
function convertToInput_koef() {
    $('td.editable_koef').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
        indicator       : 'Сохраняется...',
        name            : 'KOEF_koef',
        id              : 'ROWID_koef',
        sendMonthKoef   : $('#info-month-count').text()
    }
```

Comment: Скажите какой третий параметр и можно html таблицы?

Comment: @Genson, я дополнил свой вопрос как вы и просили, посмотрите пожалуйста еще раз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать sudmitdata (дополнительный параметр для передачи), так:

```
function convertToInput_koef() {
    $('td.editable_koef').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
        indicator       : 'Сохраняется...',
        name            : 'KOEF_koef',
        id              : 'ROWID_koef',
        submitdata      : function() {
                                 return {
                                      sendMonthKoef : $('#info-month-count').text()
                                 };
                          }
}
```

или так:

```
 function convertToInput_koef() {
        $('td.editable_koef').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', {
            indicator       : 'Сохраняется...',
            name            : 'KOEF_koef',
            id              : 'ROWID_koef',
            submitdata      : { sendMonthKoef : $('#info-month-count').text()}
 }
```

Comment: @Genson вы гений :) Спасибо огромное. А сколько максимум параметров можно отправить? или таким вот способом через **submitdata** можно сколько угодно?

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста! Сколько угодно.

Comment: @Genson, Евгений! а не подскажите как можно добавить условие проверки, в случае если пытаются засабмитить пустое поле, т.е. поле очистили и нажимают на ENTER? вот [здесь][1] тему создал [1]:http://hashcode.ru/questions/274936/jquery-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE